# Check un check radio buttons

Tags: jquery, html

I have 2 radio buttons but unable to check and uncheck

For example:-

https://jsfiddle.net/wvxsu9rb/

```
<input type=radio>National
<br>
<input type=radio>Divisions
```

When I check 'National' how do I again uncheck it?

How can I do it using Jquery?

Comment: You should use a checkbox instead of a radio button

Answer (score 2):

Give the same name in name attribute of radio tags:

```
<input type=radio name="abc">National
<br>
<input type=radio name="abc">Divisions
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
$('input:radio').on('click', function(){
    $(this).attr('checked', !$(this).attr('checked'));
});
```

Working JSFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/wvxsu9rb/1/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jquery, you must add the "name" attribute to your radios

```
<input type=radio name="groupe1">National
<input type=radio name="groupe1">Divisions
```